# Attach JS event to "Share" FB button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the "Like + Share" button on my webpages. I use the         `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', myFunction)` to attach a callback to the Like action. It works really well.

I would like to have a callback on the Share action but it seems to be out of the scope of FB.Event:

- `edge.create` does not fire with the share button
- `message.send` only fires with the send button

Did I miss something? Do you have a solution to attach a callback in this configuration?

Sources: [FB Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2) - [FB Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2)

Comment: This is something the SDK does not support, what is your use-case?

Comment: I would like to trigger a push in google analytics when the visitor complete a "Share this". I'm already able to follow how many click on "Like" but I'm loosing the one who decide to "Share this".